# error Undefined offset : 6 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to import data from excel to my database, 
The database sucessfully inserted but an error offset : 6 show. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my array?

## Controller :

```
$user = $this->input->post('user');
$path = "assets/excel/Book1.xls";

$this->load->library('excel_reader');
$this->excel_reader->read($path);
$data = $this->excel_reader->sheets[0] ;

$dataexcel = Array();

 for ($i = 2; $i <= $data['numRows']; $i++) {
    if($data['cells'][$i][2] == '')
      break;
    $dataexcel[$i-2]['item_id'] = $data['cells'][$i][2];
    $dataexcel[$i-2]['measure_cd_from'] = $data['cells'][$i][3];
    $dataexcel[$i-2]['qty_from'] = $data['cells'][$i][4];
    $dataexcel[$i-2]['measure_cd_to'] = $data['cells'][$i][5];
    $dataexcel[$i-2]['qty_to'] = $data['cells'][$i][6];
```

}

```
$this->prodConv->insertConvtData($dataexcel);
$this->load->view('formSukses');
```

## Model :

```
function insertConvtData($dataarray)
{
for($i=0;$i<count($dataarray);$i++){
       $data = array(
           'item_id'=>$dataarray[$i]['item_id'],
           'measure_cd_from'=>$dataarray[$i]['measure_cd_from'],
           'qty_from'=>$dataarray[$i]['qty_from'],
           'measure_cd_to'=>$dataarray[$i]['measure_cd_to'],
           'qty_to'=>$dataarray[$i]['qty_to']
         );

         $this->db->insert('tb_t_product_convertion',$data);
}
}
```

Comment: why r u using like that?? for ($i = 2; $i <= $data['numRows']; $i++)

Comment: im trying to store a specific coloumn in excel to array (not all columns in excel store to db)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your `for loop` as like that:

```
$j = 2; // initialize an integer with 2 for values
for ($i = 0; $i <= $data['numRows']; $i++) {
    if($data['cells'][$i][2] == '')
      break;
    $dataexcel[$i]['item_id'] = $data['cells'][$j][2];
    $dataexcel[$i]['measure_cd_from'] = $data['cells'][$j][3];
    $dataexcel[$i]['qty_from'] = $data['cells'][$j][4];
    $dataexcel[$i]['measure_cd_to'] = $data['cells'][$j][5];
    $dataexcel[$i]['qty_to'] = $data['cells'][$j][6];
    $j++;
}
```

Actually you want to use $i in both `array key` and `array value` and you try to use with only one incremental variable.

When your loop work on last iteration it will return you the `undefined`.

So, its better to use an another incremental variable for `array value`.

Comment: thx for the answer, the problem is sloved. The error : my program cant handle null data ini excel, so when i fill all the field in excel file its run with no error